# How to get the ARM tool chain with poky?

Tags: sdk, arm, installation, yocto

I want to get the software `arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-objdump` with poky at such path `/opt/poky/2.4/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-objdump`

But I am not familiar with poky, how do I get this?

---

Add:

I have solved this question.

You can download the corresponding tool chain from `http://downloads.yoctoproject.org/releases/yocto/yocto-2.4/toolchain/x86_64/`.

For example you want the ARM tool chain you can download `poky-glibc-x86_64-core-image-sato-armv5e-toolchain-2.4.sh`.

Comment: Then post this as solution. You can accept it after 2 days. More answered questions ;)

Answer (score 2):

Download the corresponding tool chain from the site:

http://downloads.yoctoproject.org/releases/yocto/yocto-2.4/toolchain/x86_64/.

For the ARM tool-chain you can download

`poky-glibc-x86_64-core-image-sato-armv5e-toolchain-2.4.sh` and bash it and include it in your build environment.